# Como posicionar corretamente o popover (Ionic3)

Tags: javascript, css, ionic, typescript, ionic3

Preciso posicionar o meu popover exatamente ao lado do botão (more) que tem dentro de cada item. Sempre que clico no botão more, o popover é acionado, porém ele fica sempre na mesma posição independente do item que eu clico. Como eu posso resolver este problema?
Obs: O meu popover é um componente, até tentei algumas estilizações de css, mas foi sem sucesso, ele continua fixando o popover em uma única posição.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of itens">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-2>
        <ion-avatar item-start>
          <img src="{{item.foto}}" *ngIf="item.foto">
          <img src="../../assets/imgs/sem_foto.png" *ngIf="!item.foto">
        </ion-avatar>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-6>
        <h3>{{item.nome}}</h3>
        <p>Estoque: {{item.quantidadeTotal}}</p>
        <button ion-button outline color="primary"
                icon-only (click)="mostrarGrades(item)">
                Grades
                <ion-icon name="arrow-dropdown"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-2>
        <h4>01/01/2019</h4>
        <h5 *ngIf="item.vlrVenda">R$ {{item.vlrVenda}}</h5>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-1>
        <button ion-button small color="primary" clear
                (click)="popoverAcoesItem(item)">
                <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <div *ngIf="item.mostrar">
      <ion-row *ngFor="let grade of item.grades">
        <ion-col col-8>
          <h6>{{grade.nomeComposto}}</h6>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-2>
          <h6>{{grade.quantidade}}</h6>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-2>
          <button ion-button small clear color="dark"
                  (click)="detalhesItemGrade(grade)">
                  Ver tudo
          </button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </div>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

O que tentei para o popover até o momento:

```
.popover-top-right .popover-content {
   transform: translateX(10%) !important;
   margin-top: -50px;
 }
```

Está ficando dessa forma:

1º item da lista : 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2º item da lista:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Resolvido da seguinte forma: `<ion-col col-1>
            <button ion-button small color="primary" clear
                    (click)="popoverAcoesItem($event)">
                    <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
            </button>
          </ion-col>`

Comment: E no ts: E no ts: `popoverAcoesItem(myEvent){
    this.itens = this.itens.map( data => {
      this.teste = data;
    })
    let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(PopoverListaItensComponent, {item: this.teste}, 
        {cssClass: 'popover-top-right'});
    popover.present({
      ev: myEvent
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      popover.dismiss();
    }, 3000);
  }`